# No module named 'tensorflow' jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have some trouble with the Jupyter Notebook Windows version. I've been tried to download TensorFlow via using this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3
After the process I just compile it and again it gave me the same error message."ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'"
In the "venv environment" I already downloaded the Jupyter notebook there too.
I check the kernel list.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Büşra>jupyter kernelspec list
```

It give me this. Should I replace the kernel list?

```
c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\share\jupyter\kernels\python3

(venv) C:\Users\Büşra> pip list
```

(venv) C:\Users\Büşra>pip list
Package              Version

---

absl-py              0.8.1
astor                0.8.0
attrs                19.3.0
backcall             0.1.0
bleach               3.1.0
cachetools           3.1.1
certifi              2019.9.11
chardet              3.0.4
colorama             0.4.1
cycler               0.10.0
decorator            4.4.1
defusedxml           0.6.0
entrypoints          0.3
gast                 0.2.2
google-auth          1.7.0
google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.1
google-pasta         0.1.8
grpcio               1.25.0
h5py                 2.10.0
idna                 2.8
importlib-metadata   0.23
ipykernel            5.1.3
ipython              7.9.0
ipython-genutils     0.2.0
ipywidgets           7.5.1
jedi                 0.15.1
Jinja2               2.10.3
joblib               0.14.0
json5                0.8.5
jsonschema           3.1.1
jupyter              1.0.0
jupyter-client       5.3.4
jupyter-console      6.0.0
jupyter-core         4.6.1
jupyterlab           1.2.2
jupyterlab-server    1.0.6
Keras                2.3.1
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
kiwisolver           1.1.0
Markdown             3.1.1
MarkupSafe           1.1.1
matplotlib           3.1.1
mistune              0.8.4
more-itertools       7.2.0
nbconvert            5.6.1
nbformat             4.4.0
nltk                 3.4.5
notebook             6.0.2
numpy                1.17.3
oauthlib             3.1.0
opt-einsum           3.1.0
pandas               0.25.3
pandocfilters        1.4.2
parso                0.5.1
pickleshare          0.7.5
pip                  19.3.1
prometheus-client    0.7.1
prompt-toolkit       2.0.10
protobuf             3.10.0
pyasn1               0.4.7
pyasn1-modules       0.2.7
Pygments             2.4.2
pyparsing            2.4.4
pyrsistent           0.15.5
python-dateutil      2.8.1
pytz                 2019.3
pywin32              225
pywinpty             0.5.5
PyYAML               5.1.2
pyzmq                18.1.0
qtconsole            4.5.5
requests             2.22.0
requests-oauthlib    1.3.0
rsa                  4.0
scikit-learn         0.21.3
scipy                1.3.1
seaborn              0.9.0
Send2Trash           1.5.0
setuptools           41.6.0
six                  1.13.0
sklearn              0.0
tensorboard          2.0.1
tensorflow           2.0.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.0.1
termcolor            1.1.0
terminado            0.8.2
testpath             0.4.4
tornado              6.0.3
traitlets            4.3.3
urllib3              1.25.6
virtualenv           16.7.7
wcwidth              0.1.7
webencodings         0.5.1
Werkzeug             0.16.0
wheel                0.33.6
widgetsnbextension   3.5.1
wrapt                1.11.2
zipp                 0.6.0

Comment: You can do pip list in your venv to see which all packages are available. And, are you sure your jupyter kernel is pointing to your venv python?

Comment: Yes , it writes jupyterlab not jupyter notebook .Is that OK?

Comment: Try finding the location of your python interpreter and see if it points to correct location. `import sys

print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Today, again I wrote to the command line - pip install tensorflow. And it worked !! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command line -
pip install tensorflow.

Comment: How are you installing it - via anaconda or jupyter command line?

Comment: Tried both of them , last one was the anaconda.

Comment: No again both of them

Comment: Today ,again I wrote to the command line - pip install tensorflow. And it worked !! Thank you for that .

Comment: This is great!
Did you deleted any history or restarted the executing environments ?

Comment: No, i didn't. I just wrote the instruction on the normal command line.